# How to restart Rock Paper and Scissors game mutliple times until user quits in Java

Tags: java

Hello I'm stuck on how to keep the game going until the user decides to quit. I want to try any way possible to get the game to end and display the amount of losses, ties, and wins. I'm trying to use a while loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class JavaApplication15 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ties = 0, wins = 0, losses = 0;
        String comp = "";
        String user = "";
        Random choice = new Random();
        String startover = "y";
        while (startover.equals("y")) {
            int computerchoice = choice.nextInt(3) + 1;

            if (computerchoice == 1)
                comp = "R";
            else if (computerchoice == 2)
                comp = "P";
            else if (computerchoice == 3)
                comp = "S";

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter rock (1), paper (2), or scissors (3) [no to quit]: ");
            int player = scanner.nextInt();

            if (player == 1) {
                user = "R";
            } else if (player == 2) {
                user = "P";
            } else if (player == 3) {
                user = "S";
            }

            System.out.println("You choose: " + user);
            System.out.println("Computer chooses: " + comp);

            if (comp.equals(user)) {
                System.out.println("It's a tie!");
                ties++;
            } else if (user.equals("R")) {
                if (comp.equals("P"))
                    System.out.println("Computer wins! Paper beats rock!");
                losses++;
            } else if (comp.equals("S")) {
                System.out.println("You win! Your rock beats the scissors!");
                wins++;
            } else if (user.equals("S")) {
                if (comp.equals("P"))
                    System.out.println("You win! Scissor beats paper!");
                wins++;
            } else if (comp.equals("R")) {
                System.out.println("Computer wins! Rock beats paper!");
                losses++;
            } else if (user.equals("P"))
                if (comp.equals("R")) {
                    System.out.println("You win! Paper beats rock!");
                    wins++;
                } else if (comp.equals("S")) {
                    System.out.println("Computer wins! Scissors beats paper!");
                    losses++;
                }
        }

        {
            System.out.println("Invalid input! Try again");

            System.out.println("Your ties: " + ties);
            System.out.println("Your wins: " + wins);
            System.out.println("You losses: " + losses);
            startover = "no";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you have a specific problem or are you asking us to write code for you?

Comment: I just have a specific problem in how to get the code to make restart. Like why can't I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of doing scanner.nextInt(); you could do

```
System.out.println("Enter rock (1), paper (2), or scissors (3) [\'n\' to quit]: ");

char selection = scanner.nextLine().charAt(0)
if(selection == '1'){ user = "R"; }
else if(selection == '2'){ user = "P"; }
else if(selection == '3'){ user = "S"; }
else if(selection == 'n'){
    System.out.println(ties)
    System.out.println(wins);
    System.out.println(losses);
    return;
    }
```

this makes the selection variable a char, and you can test if it's 1, 2, or 3 (that is, the characters 1 2 or 3), and also check for 'n'.

since you're working in the main method, simply putting "return" will exit the program at that point.

Answer (score 0):

You just need add a new option 4

```
 else if (computerchoice == 4)
                comp = "E";

} else if (comp.equals("E")) {
        System.out.println("Your ties: " + ties);
        System.out.println("Your wins: " + wins);
        System.out.println("You losses: " + losses);
        startover = "no";
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your code as-is, and what I found out is that your code infact **never** stops. The while loop has no proper condition to exit. So I made some minor changes to make it work.

```
   int ties = 0, wins = 0, losses = 0;
   String comp = "";
   String user = "";
   Random choice = new Random();
   String startover = "y";
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); //Scanner object should not be open in loop, it is a resource wastage
   while (startover.equals("y")) {
       int computerchoice = choice.nextInt(3) + 1;

       if (computerchoice == 1)
           comp = "R";
       else if (computerchoice == 2)
           comp = "P";
       else if (computerchoice == 3)
           comp = "S";


       System.out.println("Enter rock (1), paper (2), or scissors (3) [no to quit]: ");
       String input = scanner.nextLine(); //take input in string
       int player ;
       try {
           player = Integer.parseInt(input); //see if actually number was given as input
       } catch(Exception ex) {
           break; //if not, then we assume player wants to quit
       }

       if (player == 1) {
           user = "R";
       } else if (player == 2) {
           user = "P";
       } else if (player == 3) {
           user = "S";
       }

       System.out.println("You choose: " + user);
       System.out.println("Computer chooses: " + comp);

       if (comp.equals(user)) {
           System.out.println("It's a tie!");
           ties++;
       } else if (user.equals("R")) {
           if (comp.equals("P"))
               System.out.println("Computer wins! Paper beats rock!");
           losses++;
       } else if (comp.equals("S")) {
           System.out.println("You win! Your rock beats the scissors!");
           wins++;
       } else if (user.equals("S")) {
           if (comp.equals("P"))
               System.out.println("You win! Scissor beats paper!");
           wins++;
       } else if (comp.equals("R")) {
           System.out.println("Computer wins! Rock beats paper!");
           losses++;
       } else if (user.equals("P"))
           if (comp.equals("R")) {
               System.out.println("You win! Paper beats rock!");
               wins++;
           } else if (comp.equals("S")) {
               System.out.println("Computer wins! Scissors beats paper!");
               losses++;
           }
   }


   scanner.close();    //scanner was not closed before
   System.out.println("Your ties: " + ties);
   System.out.println("Your wins: " + wins);
   System.out.println("You losses: " + losses);
   startover = "no"; //redundant actually
```